# in-page acoustic warnings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I need to create an acoustic warning in a PHP backed page that plays when certain conditions in PHP are met.

The only way of how to do this I can think of is conditional embedding of a small flash file that would play the sound upon rendering in browser... However, this seems as a bit out of date practice to me... Something like the JS alert() sound would be sufficient (I have considered using the alert() way too). Or the Facebook chat message notification sound...

Any other ideas how this could be done? Preferably using jQuery / JS etc...

(not looking for any complete solution / code etc, just point me in the right direction... if there is any)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Audio

Comment: Browsers should not emit sounds unless requested by the user [e.g. youtube, soundcloud]. In case you absolutely need, [check this](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) - it has flash fallbacks for unsupported features.

Comment: @moonwave99 - I know, however, it's an internal system. It gets data from the ECB, saves and compares them with a database and plays a sound when an exchange rate changes beyond limit and thus needs user's attention...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HTML5 audio element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)

```
<audio src="audio.ogg" controls autoplay loop>
     <p>Your browser does not support the audio element </p>
</audio>
```

Popular JS library is [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)

Comment: thanx. html5 is not an option since it has to support older browsers, i'll go with SoundManager2...

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your js when the condition you want is met :

```
var snd='<audio autoplay="true"><source src="sound.mp3"></audio>';  
$('body').append(snd);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and simply I used this:

```
if($condition)
  echo "<embed src='/file/sound/alert.swf' />"
```